# Difference between two ways of partial application in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Let's say we have the following function (body isn't very important):

```
let writelogf greeting x = 
    Printf.printf "%A" greeting
    Printf.printf "%A" x
```

The type of this function is `'a -> 'b -> unit` which is what I want.

Now I define a partially applied function:

```
let logf x = writelogf "Hello!" x
```

The type of this function is `'a -> unit` which is what I expect. I'm able to use it with arguments of any type:

```
logf "Test"
logf 1
```

But if I try to simplify the declaration and repeat the calls:

```
let logf2 = writelogf "Hello!"
logf2 "Test"
logf2 1
```

it won't compile anymore, because `logf2` is not generalized, it has type `string -> unit` (infered from first usage).

Why is that? If I have a function with 5 parameters and I need to partially apply one, do I have to repeat the other 4?

Comment: `let inline …` may also be a solution, depending on your goals.

Comment: @bytebuster inline need to have a function, not a value ; and with a function the problem is already "solved" inline or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case where you have written:

```
let logf2 = writelogf "Hello!"
```

You are effectively binding a value, the type of which is generic.  If you change your definition into a function, e.g. by taking the argument explicitly, or an argument of unit type, you can resolve the issue.

```
let logf x = writelogf "Hello!" x

let logf2() = writelogf "Hello!"
```

If you have a function with 5 parameters and you partially apply one, again you will need to take at least one argument explicitly but you do not need to repeat the other 3.

```
let test5 a b c d e =
    printfn "%A" (a, b, c, d, e)

let testApplyOne x = test5 "Hello!" x
```